# Finding a string in json object Node JS

Tags: node.js, json

I have a json file in which I have to find a string is available of not.

Example:

```
   let testjson =require('./jsontest.json');
   let string= 'abcd';
```

I would like to find if `abcd` in json object.

My json file looks like following

```
[
 { 
   name:"aaaa",
   j1:[ "abcd","efg"],
   j2:[ "abcde","xyz"]
 },
 { 
   name:"bbbbb",
   j1:[ "abcdw","efg1"],
   j2:[ "abcde12","xyz22"]
 }
]
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue in Node js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` or `some` method to find the given `string` is present or not in the  array.

Major difference between these method is `filter` return the matched `object` or an empty array if no match and `some` return `true` if any one one of item matches the condition or `false`.

[More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const json = [
 { 
   name:"aaaa",
   j1:[ "abcd","efg"],
   j2:[ "abcde","xyz"]
 },
 { 
   name:"bbbbb",
   j1:[ "abcdw","efg1"],
   j2:[ "abcde12","xyz22"]
 },
 { 
   name:"aaaa2",
   j1:[ "abcds","efg"],
   j2:[ "abcd","xyz"]
 },
]


const string = "abcd"

const result = json.filter(data=>{
  const {j1,j2} = data;
  return j1.includes(string) || j2.includes(string)
});

console.log(result); // return the matched object

const isFound = json.some(data=>{
  const {j1,j2} = data;
  return j1.includes(string) || j2.includes(string)
});

console.log(isFound); // return boolean
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The example that you have given have objects and string in the json file. You can use a recursive function to search for a string within a `JSON object` and you can use `includes` to check if if has the string or not, something like:

```
  const fs = require('fs')
    
    function searchJson(obj, targetString) {
     for (const key in obj) {
         if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            if (searchJson(obj[key], targetString)) {
            return true;
          }
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'string' && obj[key].includes(targetString)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    
    const testjson = require('./jsontest.json');
    const searchString = 'abcd';
    
    const isStringFound = searchJson(testjson, searchString);
    
    if (isStringFound) {
      console.log(`The string '${searchString}' is found.`);
    } else { 
      console.log(`The string '${searchString}' is not found .`);
    }
```

replace `testjson` with your JSON object and `searchString` with the string you want to search for in your json .